# How to find where Drush is installed to include a file in my module?

Tags: drush

I have installed the module [Drush Help](https://www.drupal.org/project/drush_help) to see the module's Drush commands in the module help page. But when I go to see the help page of a module that use in the drush commands drush constants like DRUSH_BOOTSTRAP_DRUPAL_FULL I got a Notice because this constant is only defined in drush, and not for Drupal.

You can see this problem if you install the [Drush Help](https://www.drupal.org/project/drush_help) and the [Node Revision Delete](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_revision_delete) modules (the Drupal 7 version): Visit `admin/help/node_revision_delete` and you will see this notice message.

> Notice: Use of undefined constant DRUSH_BOOTSTRAP_DRUPAL_FULL - assumed 'DRUSH_BOOTSTRAP_DRUPAL_FULL' in node_revision_delete_drush_command()

So the problem is that Drupal can't reach the file includes/bootstrap.inc where the constant is defined. I can include the file but the problem is that I need to know where Drush is installed.

How to find where Drush is installed to include a file in my module?

Comment: In bash: `ll \`which drush\`` will give you the path to the binary, which is very likely the path to the root of the installation

Comment: @Clive but always ll will not be available in all the systems.

Comment: Yeah you’ll need to adjust for your own environment obviously. However you list files, use that

Comment: @Clive well I found a temporary solution. See the answer.

Answer (score 1):

A temporary solution that I found is define the same constants in the drush_help.module file.

```
/**
 * Constants defined by drush in the includes/bootstrap.inc file.
 *
 * To see why we need to do this please read:
 * https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/250786/28275
 */
define('DRUSH_BOOTSTRAP_NONE', -1);
define('DRUSH_BOOTSTRAP_MAX', -2);
define('DRUSH_BOOTSTRAP_DRUSH', 0);
define('DRUSH_BOOTSTRAP_DRUPAL_ROOT', 1);
define('DRUSH_BOOTSTRAP_DRUPAL_SITE', 2);
define('DRUSH_BOOTSTRAP_DRUPAL_CONFIGURATION', 3);
define('DRUSH_BOOTSTRAP_DRUPAL_DATABASE', 4);
define('DRUSH_BOOTSTRAP_DRUPAL_FULL', 5);
define('DRUSH_BOOTSTRAP_DRUPAL_LOGIN', 6);
```